# Phonegap Build Notification with multiple Input Fields

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm new to Phonegap Build and what I'm trying to figure out is if there's a way to prompt the user with two input fields in one dialog like the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI08D.png).

I'm using the Notification plugin and target both Android and iOS.

Best Regards
Mattias Berggren

Comment: The only way I know is to use a modal window.

Comment: Any tips on where I can find more information on what you are refering to?

Comment: Use a javascript library like jquery mobile, there you can create modal windows with no great knowledge.

Comment: Was hoping to be able to solve it without designing my own notifications (or use existing libraries) but seems to be no way then. Thx for you answers by the way.